# Mobile screen does not display Primary navbar...just a three line icon

Tags: menus

Working in WP 4.8.1... set up working Primary Navbar, works fine on website. However, does not display at all on mobile phones. What am I missing?

Comment: This is most likely to be related to the theme you've chosen and not directly to WordPress. Please try reaching out to the theme author for support.

Comment: Most likely, the "three line icon" you're seeing is a [Hamburger button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button). If you click it, the menu should expand.

Answer (score 1):

Many themes are 'responsive', so they adjust the content to the size of the device.  As part of the responsive aspects of the theme, the theme CSS adjusts the menu to show up as the 'hamburger' icon (the three bars) which denotes the menu location.

So, the menu display as the 'hamburger' is normal on smaller screens, part of the responsive CSS that the theme uses.

You might find this tutorial typical of how a 'hamburger' menu is displayed on smaller screens: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp .

Answer (score 0):

Its mobile menu as Rick explained it.

You can usually find it in your header.php

```
<button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'test' ); ?></button>
```